# Merging two dataframes with different keys of different data types in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes

master

```
P_ID      C_ID   D_ID ...
520686814 1222   1281
336892632 1232   8181 ...
```

and

```
str(master$P_ID) : integer64 [1:12000] 520686814 336892632 140101133 85433815 339389222
```

Also

Dimension

```
p_id      year  gender state
520686814 2017  1      A
336892632 2016  2      B
```

and

```
str(Dimension$p_id) : num [1:9915433] 520686814 336892632 636774575 248552775...
```

So essentially I can see that there are records matching in both dataframes for a p_id. So I do a join using

```
joined <- merge(master, Dimension, by.x = "P_ID", by.y = "p_id")
```

And to my surprise, I get no records in joined. Does the join don't work on different data types even though they work while subsetting?

Comment: Is `integer64` an R atomic class? Depending on which package you use, it might store `integer64` as a `character`. Then it should be clear to see why your merge doesn't work. Could you clarify how you generated `integer64` data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're not performing any mathematical operations on them you could (some would argue should) store IDs as character strings instead. It's my understanding that this is a safer approach. Additionally, merging on strings is faster than merging on numerics.

```
master$P_ID <- as.character(master$P_ID)
Dimension$p_id <- as.character(Dimension$p_id)
joined <- merge(master, Dimension, by.x = "P_ID", by.y = "p_id")
```

The code above should get it done. It doesn't answer the question of why your merge fails but does provide you with a workaround.

Comment: Actually, my question is more focused on why the merge failed, I did a similar workaround by converting master$P_ID <- as.numeric(master$P_ID). Although now that you mention that string merging is faster, I could probably do that. Still, would wait for any explanation on the Why part

Comment: @hbabbar ... what is that *integer64* type as it is not a base R atomic type? Is it a special class you define or a another package? As commented above, please post **all** libraries used.

Comment: @Parfait I was confused by that too. After you pointing it out, I inspected and I found that I had used fread from data.table to import my data and it had implicitly read the data as integer64. When i tried it back from read.csv, it was numeric. This was a new observation for me.